# Which Java technology should be used to build client-server applications on the server side?

Tags: java, apache-flex, blazeds

I'm new in the Java world and I'm totally confused with the sheer number of Java server-side technologies.  I need to build application with Java on the server side and Flex-AIR on the client.  All communication between them must be on sockets and in AMF format.

Which technology would be suitable for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think tha given your constraints you should be looking at Blaze: http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/blazeds/BlazeDS/

Comment: yeah, I forgot about that) Thx)

Answer (score 2):

JPA+Spring. You can create service layer with Spring, and use it from you flex client.

Comment: If BlazeDS thing won't work I'll follow your advice. Thank you)